# PHP - Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

Tags: php, php-openssl

I have check a lot of the questions that are in Stackoverflow and I don't find anything helpful.

I have debug the error,

> Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

and it comes from this line:

```
$this->secret_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(
       "file://$this->rootDir/config/jwt/private.pem", getenv('JWT_PASSPHRASE'));
```

I also try:

```
    $file = file_get_contents("file://$this->rootDir/config/jwt/private.pem");
    $this->secret_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($file, getenv('JWT_PASSPHRASE'));
```

If I debug the `$file` I get the complete content of the file.

But when I run `openssl_pkey_get_private` I also get **FALSE**.

As our docker (for local and devel server) it's a debian and the staging server it's Ubuntu 18.04, so I try to create news `pem` files for the staging server, but I get the same error.

Any idea what's going on with this?

Comment: I guess the file format or the passphrase is wrong

Comment: Are you using absolute path or relative path? for absolute path on unix-based systems please try file:///$this->rootDir/config/jwt/private.pem with 3 */* (`file:///`)

Comment: @shingo as it's working in another enviroment it can not be wrong; We have the pem file in Git also, and the passphrase it's in the .env file

Comment: `getenv` may return unexpected variable, try test with raw text. and as you said it's working in another environment, are the 2 environments also same? the version of openssl extension.